# Using URLs with parenthesis with Lynx

Tags: command-line, url, lynx

I often use Lynx on a remote computer to look at websites (faster than port-forwarding). 
Sometimes the URLs I want to go to have un-escaped characters (for example brackets) that Lynx seems to need encoded.
for example 
`http://www.example.com/This(URL)is anExample.html`
should be
`http://www.example.com/This%28URL%29is%20anExample.html`.

Is there an existing script for this? 
Alternatively is there some option for Lynx that would make it unnecessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape a string on the command line by using single ticks, so

```
lynx 'http://www.example.com/This(URL)is anExample.html'
```

Will pass the URL unchanged to lynx, or any other program.